# End of line character for regular expressions in ml-lex

Tags: lex, sml

What is the *end of line character* for regular expressions in ml-lex?
"`$`"  is used for catching the *end of line character* in regular expressions in most other languages, but if I use it in case of ml-lex, it gives me an error -

```
mllex a.lex
ml-lex: error, line 45: lookahead is unimplemented
unhandled exception: Error
```

I am currently appending all my regular expressions with an additional `\n` character for explicitly catching the end of line character. However removing the caught extra `\n` character is making the code ugly.

I read somewhere that `$` is not implemented in ml-lex.
So, can there be any other solution for my problem? Please help.

Comment: Can you show us what your mllex input looks like? I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do. Ordinarily I'd avoid making things require a pattern at end-of-line or lex '\n' separately and deal with it in the parser.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it looks like the `$` character is not implemented in ML-Lex according to [this manual](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/ML-Lex/manual.html):

> "The dollar sign of C Lex $ is not implemented, since it is an
>   abbreviation for lookahead involving the newline character (that is,
>   it is an abbreviation for /\n)."

And it is also noted in [this user guide](http://rogerprice.org/ug/ug.pdf):

> "The dollar sign of C Lex $ is not implemented, since it is an
>   abbreviation for lookahead involving the newline character that is, it
>   is an abbreviation for /\n."

*So... that would at least explain (and back up your reading of the `$` not being implemented in ML-Lex).  Unfortunately, that probably means that for now, at least, you might just need to keep using your existing method for checking those end-of-lines... even it doesn't look super clean.*